# Converting multitrack audio of an mkv video file w/ ffmpeg

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I have mkv files with multitrack AAC audio which have to be converted to PCM-S16-BE. The following command works but creates a video with only one stereo track:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16be output.mkv`

To convert all three audio tracks I tried this which runs without giving an error:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v copy -c:a:1 pcm_s16be -c:a:2 pcm_s16be -c:a:3 pcm_s16be output.mkv`

But the output file contains only one stereo track.

ffmpeg gives the following information on the input.mkv file:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4.1-3+b2 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Debian 11.2.0-18)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=3+b2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:50.42, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2889 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:50.417000000
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Track1
      DURATION        : 00:00:50.368000000
  Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      title           : Track2
      DURATION        : 00:00:50.368000000
  Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      title           : Track3
      DURATION        : 00:00:50.368000000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `-map 0` (right after `-i input.mkv`)

Comment: Works, great! Thank you, that did it! All the best to you!

Comment: Please don't put 'solved' in the title. This isn't reddit. Write an answer, mark it correct, then others can see it has an accepted answer. [It's perfectly acceptable & even encouraged, if the person who gave you the clue didn't add an answer themselves, to do it yourself.]

Comment: Okay, thanks for the hint, I appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows, use `-map 0` like this:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a:1 pcm_s16be -c:a:2 pcm_s16be -c:a:3 pcm_s16be output.mkv`

Thanks to Tom Yan!

Comment: It is possible, that the result is one empty audio channel. In my case it helped to change the numbering of c:a like this: `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a:0 pcm_s16be -c:a:1 pcm_s16be -c:a:2 pcm_s16be output.mkv`. It worked, although ffmpeg showed another numbering in its file information. A bit weird, but so what?

Comment: The indices to specify should be zero-based and because of `:a`, only the audio streams are counted. But the output message from ffmpeg about the streams counts all the streams one by one regardless of their type (yet also zero-based), so when there are 4 (1+3) streams in total, you see `#0:0`, `#0:1`, `#0:2`, `#0:3`. (I'm not sure if you can use `-c` without `:a` or `:v` *but with* an index. You may try if interested. (Btw, `-c:a pcm_s16be1` should be sufficient to you need.)

Comment: @Tom Yan: Unfortunately, the short version `-c:a pcm_s16be1` leaves me with only one stereo audiotrack. So as far as my experiments went, I have to enumerate all tracks. Thx for the explanation of the numbering scheme <3 !